# Nested perform needs and doesn't need an end-perform

Tags: cobol

With this code, I get

```
16: Perform stmnt not terminated by end-perform

33: syntax error, unexpected end-perform
```

Why is it saying that I need an end-perform and also not need it?

```
   identification division.
   program-id.  xxx.     
  * will accept and display a num until 0 is called then
  * asks to go again


   data division.
   file section.

   working-storage section.     
   01  num                 pic 9(4).
   01  hold                pic 9(4).
   01  another             pic x.
   procedure division.
     perform until another = 'N'                 (line 16)
        Display "Another Session (Y/N)? "
              with no advancing
        if another = 'Y'
        Display "Enter a 4-digit unsigned number (0 to stop): "
             with no advancing
        accept num
        move num to hold
        perform until num = 0
        Display "Enter a 4-digit unsigned number (0 to stop): "
             with no advancing
        accept num
          if num <> 0
       move num to hold
        end-perform.
        display space
        Display "The last number entered: "hold
     End-perform.                            (Line 33)

     stop run.
```

Comment: The etiquette of the site is that you Accept the answer which most helps you get to the solution you require. There should be a thing which looks like a tick below the down arrow to the left of an answer. If you Accept, it shows other searchers what helped you towards your solution. Of course, when you have enough reputation, you can upvote on any answers which helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   end-perform.
    display space
    Display "The last number entered: "hold
 End-perform.                            (Line 33)
```

It's that full-stop/period (Line 30) which is the killer.

Although since the 1985 Standard COBOL is much more relaxed about full-stops/periods, a single one will bring all current scopes screaming to a halt. You could have nesting 50 levels deep, and one single full-stop/period would end them all, in one fell swoop.

My advice is to use the absolute minimum of full-stop/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION.

That is: one to terminate the PROCEDURE DIVISION header; one to terminate each paragraph/SECTION label; one to terminate a paragrpah/SECTION; one to terminate a program (for a program with no paragraphs/SECTIONS). Also, if you have PROCEDURE DIVISION COPY or REPLACE statements, you'll need full-stops/periods to terminate those.

Except for the termination of the labels I put each full-stop/period on a line of its own, never attached to any code. I can then move code around and insert code without worrying about whether I need to add/remove a full-stop/period.

As to why you need END-PERFORM, it is an "inline PERFORM". Syntactically, an inline PERFORM requires an END-PERFORM, but your use of the full-stop/period caused termination of the PERFORM scope before the END-PERFORM was located, so the error on line 16. Subsequently an END-PERFORM unconnected to a PERFORM was located, so the error on line 33.

It is important when putting error messages in your questions that you *include the error message exactly as you see it*. Copy/paste, don't re-trype, please. Include any message numbers, as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  very insightful for a new cobolist

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can not mix the full stop "." scope terminator from Cobol-74 with the End-* scope terminators from Cobol-85.

The difference is that the full stop "." terminates ALL scopes.

The End-* terminates only the most recent scope, just like you might expect.

Putting a "." in the middle of code with End-* is kinda like dropping a nuclear bomb in the middle of it.  As a rule, for compilers made in the last quarter century or so, a period should only occur in the procedure division at the end of a paragraph name, or at the end of a paragraph (and sections too, but those are useless in an age where segmentation and overlays are managed by the operating system).  I like to use "EXIT." or "CONTINUE." just to highlight that I'm using one of the bad-nasty-best-avoided-periods in the procedure division.